# Reliable way to know if the user allows storage of Local Shared Objects (LSO)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3

There is a small feature I have implemented that makes uses of the Local Shared Objects to work properly.

I wish to be able to help the user self-diagnose if he is unable to use the said feature because he refused access for this computer to writing local shared objects and give him instructions to work around the issue if it applies to him.

I'm looking for something similar to the muted property of the Microphone class (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html) or the Camera class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ShardObject reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2), `SharedObject.getLocal()` throws an `Error` if the user has set the Flash Player to not allow Shared Objects. Wrap a probing call to said function in a try/catch block and you'll know whether or not you can rely on them. Since I'm not sure if that covers all cases (e.g. Shared Objects being blocked by a third party browser add-on), I'd try to store and reload some test data.

Comment: I am embarassed by how i've just read that page and missed that thing. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that LSO storage may succeed, but be deleted between sessions -- see for example the "Better Privacy" Firefox extension.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get an error to be thrown while calling the getLocal() method when LSO is disabled but the flush method did the trick.

Also thanks for the great tip Andrew but I think LSO should never be used to store "critical" information for this exact reason.